# Format JSON data for select

Tags: json, drop-down-menu, populate

I get response as below

```
{"ValuesDTO": {"items": [{},{"default": {"size": 5},"int": 10,"string": "Product1","string": "Product1 ","string": "product3","string": "product4","string": "product5"}]}}
```

How do I populate selectbox?

Comment: You want to populate Product1, Product2,Product3, Product4, Product5 ?

Comment: yes I want to add all products in dropdown